# How do you disable other navigation link while you are in current link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, navigation

Suppose, I have navigation link ex:

```
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>   <!---- if this link will be clicked, others will be disabled unless clicked again. --->
   <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am making one page website. slide effect and display the content when clicked.

appreciate all of your help.

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ Basically, you will write something like `$("a").click(function(e){e.preventDefault()//prevent default behaviour of clicking a 'a'});` if you want to enable links again, replace `e.preventDefault()` by `return true;`. It will reaffect the default behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Maybe a little rewording?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you seeing an error?  It's hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to set the `onclick` attribute of all links to '`return false;`' (which would cause a redirection to not happen) when clicking on another link. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do your menu like

```
<a href="#Works">Works Page Section</a>
```

and then later in your page

```
<div id="Works">
//Content goes here
<a href="#Menu">Back to Menu</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... This will help you...

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#" id="li1">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="li2">Works</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="li3">about</a></li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
$("#li1").click(function(){
    $("#li2").attr("href","");
    $("#li3").attr("href","");
});
```